# get COUNT(*) from mysql_magic

Tags: php, sql

The following code retrieve the result from queries. Usually, I ask for SELECT... and I get a two-dimensional array but this time I need to get count from a table.

```
if(isset($_GET['query']))
{
    $results = mysql_magic($_GET['query']);
    $response = array();
    //ERROR : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()   
    foreach($results as &$row)
    {
        $rowArray = array();
        foreach($row as &$column)
        {
            $rowArray[] = $column;
        }
        $response[] = $rowArray;
    }

    $jsonData = json_encode($results);
}
```

This is a part of the function mysql_magic. In most cases, it returns mysql_fetch_all($req_result). In this case, it returns a row.

```
else if (startsWith($req_sql, 'select count(*)'))
{
    $line = mysql_fetch_row($req_result);
    return $line[0];
}
```

Why do I get an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" since my result, a count, contains one row and one column?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using mysql_magic($_GET['query']) should be mysql_query($_GET['query']). I see no reference in the [code](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) for a $_GET case. So $results is undefined due to php error?

```
if(isset($_GET['query']))
{
    $results = mysql_query($_GET['query']);
    $response = array();
    //ERROR : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()   
    foreach($results as &$row)
    {
        $rowArray = array();
        foreach($row as &$column)
        {
            $rowArray[] = $column;
        }
        $response[] = $rowArray;
    }

    $jsonData = json_encode($results);
}
```